# div overlay background

Tags: html

In my application am using transparent div like a show modal dialog.Its working fine in firefox but not working well in internet explorer.

What is the solution to work similar in both

Thanks

Comment: A code snippet + version of IE that it doesn't work on will help.

Answer (score 1):

IE6 needs to set an alpha-filter for transparency:

```
.transparent {
   opacity: 0.5;
   filter: alpha(opacity = 50); /* Needed for IE6 */
}
```

I would recommend to have the filter rule in a separate stylesheet for good measure.